# 3 adults, 4 girls and 5 boys will be put them into a line. All 5 boys must be next to each other. Last person in line must be adult. How many ways?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

We have 3 adults, 4 girls and 5 boys in which we are going to arrange into a line.

Stipulations:
(i) All 5 boys must be next to each other
(ii) The last person in the line must be an adult.

Question: How many ways can we create a line?

My solution attempt:

There are 3 adults, so the last place in the line has 3 possibilities

There are 5! ways in which we can rearrange the 5 boys next to each other.

Treating the five boys as a block of 1, and removing the last adult, this leaves us with: 1 block of boys + 4 girls + 2 adults = 7 items

The number of ways we can rearrange these 7 items is: 7!

So final solution: 7! x 5! x 3 = 1814400

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, your analysis is good, and your answer is correct.